# React defaultProps not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, components

By default I want my `lastMessage` prop to be an object with an id. But with the code below it comes up as `null`.

Code:

```
const App = ({ lastMessage }) => { // lastMessage is currently null

    return (
        <Message lastMessage={lastMessage} />
    )
}

class Message extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        const data = [];

        if (nextProps.lastMessage.id !== this.props.lastMessage.id) {
            log.debug('woohoo');
            // do something ...
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            // something...
        );
    }
}

Message.defaultProps = {
    lastMessage: {
        id: 0,
    },
};
```

In my `App` component I pass `lastMessage` as `null` to `Message` component. But I set `defaultProps` in `Message` component :

```
Message.defaultProps = {
    lastMessage: {
        id: 0,
    },
```

I expect `lastMessage` to be an object with an id, however it is still null. Then my app crashes because `nextProps.lastMessage.id` doesn't work if `lastMessage` is `null`

Even stranger if I remove the lastMessage prop in my App component:

```
const App = () => {

    return (
        <Message />
    )
}
```

Then the Message component creates the `lastMessage` `defaultProp` as an object with an id.

If my prop is null I am trying to pass it with a default value. I tried something like this but it still does not work:

```
const App = ({ lastMessage = { id: 0 } }) => { // lastMessage is still null

    return (
        <Message lastMessage={lastMessage} />
    )
}
```

Am I not setting the defaultProps correctly?

Comment: explictly passing `null` is acutally a value for the proptypes validation. If you pass `undefined` instead it would work. Anyways i would edit the if statement instead checking for `lastMessage` being something that evaluates to true before trying to access the `id` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `null` to Message component you basically overwrite default property - `lastMessage`. If I understood you correctly then it works when you remove passing `lastMessage` to Message component. It should stay this way.

You can do ternary truthiness check before passing argument to component:

```
<Message lastMessage={lastMessage ? lastMessage : undefined} />
```

As you've also figured out you can also pass default props this way:

```
<Message lastMessage={lastMessage ? lastMessage : { id: 0 }} />
```

Comment: but eventually lastMessage will have a real value so I want to pass it

Comment: In component will receive props check if message is not falsy before you access id.

Comment: `If you pass null to Message component you basically overwrite default property` ---- is there a way to do a check.. like if prop is null pass it with a default value?

Comment: You should do that check in your component code - `componentWillReceiveProps`. Your component code is unsafe, and what you try to do is basically work around the real problem. ;)

Comment: That's my temporary solution but in my real case I have many props that are null, I don't want to check every time ...

Comment: `<Message lastMessage={lastMessage ? lastMessage : undefined} />` - can you try that?

Comment: Awesome! that works. I can even do: `<Message lastMessage={lastMessage ? lastMessage : { id: 0 }} />`.  If you want you can add that to your answer and I will mark it as corrected.

Comment: Hey, definitely. :)